# How to use find exec cp with a regex pattern?

Tags: unix, find

I want to copy some files with string "ABC" in their name and without string "DEF" in their name using the find -exec command. This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/441422/how-do-you-use-regular-expressions-with-the-cp-command-in-linux) mentions how to do it for the without case using find command. I want to know how to do it for both with and without cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-and` or `-a` for multiple true condition as follows. `!` for negation can be applied after and

```
find . \( -regex ".*ABC.*" -and ! -regex ".*DEF.*" \)  -exec cp {} /destination/folder/ \;
```